# python django почему на localhost стили css+js работают, но при разворачивании на удаленном сервере стили не работают, чисто html отображается

Tags: javascript, css, python-3.x, django, развертывание

На локальном сервере все работает css + js + images, но на удаленном серваке стили не работают отображается голый чистый html

```
{% load static %}
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <base href="./">
    <title>Umbrella Co - Главная страница</title>
    <meta property="og:title" content="Umbrella Co - Главная страница" />
    <meta name="twitter:title" content="Umbrella Co - Главная страница" />
    <meta name="og:image" content="assets/uploads/leon.jpg?p=l6pHObFi" />
    <meta name="twitter:image" content="assets/uploads/leon.jpg?p=l6pHObFi" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com/" crossorigin>
    <!-- Compressed Styles -->
    {# <link href="css/slides.min.css?521351" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> #}
    <link type ="text/css" href="{% static 'umbrella/css/slides.min.css'%}" rel="stylesheet" />
                                                       <!-- пример css  -->
    <!-- Fonts and Material Icons -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если кратко, ваш сервер не находит / не отдает корректно статические файлы.
Думаю, что вы не настраивали веб-сервер на своей удаленной машине, а просто запустили проект стандартными локальными методами.

Рекомендую почитать [гайд от digitalocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-20-04-ru), в котором пошагово раскрывается способ развертывания проекта с использованием Linux, Django, Postgres, Nginx и Gunicorn, в процессе изучения вы самостоятельно сможете изменить связанные технологии на необходимые вам, желаю удачи!

**Дополнение:**

Может быть полезным для Apache:

```
Alias /static/ /path/to/mysite.com/static/

<Directory /path/to/mysite.com/static>
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: а у меня windows 2012 + apache, возможно здесь свои косяки ... Спасибо ВАм

Comment: Сервер настраивал по идее django бы не заработал

Comment: @almaz Django работает и без корректного отображения статических файлов

Comment: согласен полностью

Comment: @almaz Я дополнил ответ, по сути вам нужно указать апачу на то где лежат ваши статические файлы, но могут быть нюансы, не работал с этим стеком, нашел на английском в документации информацию, возможно будет полезным: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-files

Comment: хорошо попробую ))

Comment: Все спасибо Вам  Огромное пошло поехало.... действительно в apache не хватало данного пути до моего app